# How to get count of State and city of country using SQL query from database?

Tags: mysql

By running this query:

```
select 
    c.name, count(s.name) as statecount,  
    sum(count(ci.name)) OVER() AS citycount 
from 
    countries c, states s, cities ci
where 
    ci.state_id = s.id 
    and s.country_id = c.id 
group by 
    s.name
```

I need to get an output in this style:

```
Country => statecount => citycount
```

Comment: I removed the multiple database tags.  Are you using MySQL or SQLite?  Neither support window functions, so you should edit your question and include sample data and desired results.  While you are at it, fix the `FROM` clause so it uses proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results

Comment: Thanks Its working but there is no need "distinct keyword"

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: then @ChrisAllwein response is correct.  Distinct is necessary if you want a distinct count of states for the country having cities.  if each country has more than one city per state then distinct matters

Comment: we are filtering and removing duplicates because there is no need duplicate states... because "state id" matters ...... if any of data would be entered against state id it would difficult to manage.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thanks marc_s have added to my list of study.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because countries can have multiple states and each state can have multiple cities when you join these 1 to many and 1 to many many your state count is inflated.  So you need the distinct count of state.   The city count is already unique to country and state, thus doesn't need the distinct.  where as state is not unique to country city, thus distinct is needed.  This of course assumes you want the count of unique states in each country.

```
SELECT c.name, count(distinct s.name) as statecount,  count(Ci.name) as CityCount
FROM countries c
INNER JOIN states s 
  on c.id = s.country_ID
INNER JOIN cities ci
  ON s.id = ci.state_id
GROUP BY C.name
```

Or keeping your old style join notation:

```
SELECT c.name, count(distinct s.name) as statecount,  count(ci.name) citycount 
FROM countries c,states s,cities ci
WHERE ci.state_id = s.id 
  and s.country_id = c.id 
GROUP BY s.name
```

Consider the following example: http://rextester.com/ZGYF56786

or pictorially below

See when the joins occur between country, state and city. state gets repeated because of the join to city, making state no longer unique in that column, by doing a distinct we only return a count of 2 states instead of 7, one for each record.

```
+-----+------------+-------------+
| USA | Illinois   | Chicago     |
| USA | Illinois   | Springfield |
| USA | Illinois   | Peoria      |
| USA | California | LosAngeles  |
| USA | California | Sacramento  |
| USA | California | SanDeigo    |
| USA | California | Hollywood   |
| USA | California | Oakland     |
|-----|------------|-------------|
|Name | statecount | Citycount   |
| USA | 2          | 7           | <-- Is this result correct? (i hope so)
| USA | 7          | 7           | <-- or this one? (then why bother just count(*) and only 1 count needed.
+-----+------------+-------------+
```

I would think you want the 1st result since there are only 2 states in USA table listed and 7 cities.

Comment: @MithileshKumar please don't update/remove the distinct keyword.  It's correct if my assumption is.  If my assumption is incorrect, address it.

Comment: The two 1-M table joins MAKES distinct matter regardless of no duplicates in the data.  Consider the example: http://rextester.com/ZGYF56786    if you don't use distinct state count and city count will match.  If that's what you want then you really don't need to count state.  Notice two different queries one w/ distinct one w/o. and the results are different.  So if you don't need the distinct, then you're saying count the state once for each record of a city. If you have the distinct then you're saying return the count of the unique state records for the country.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Over.  This should just be a simple group-by.

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(s.name) AS statecount,  COUNT(ci.name) AS citycount 
FROM countries c
     JOIN states s
        ON c.id = s.country_id
     JOIN cities ci
        ON s.id = ci.state_id
GROUP BY c.name
```

Comment: s.name in the group by makes no sense here.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I had it in my head that he was outputting a list of countries, states, and then the city count for each.