# each state in dropdown I want total counts of records in each state in php

Tags: php, mysqli

```
Table_sup           |
+-------------------+
| supid=>int        |                
| scompany=>varchar | 
| sstate=>varchar   | 
| scity=>varchar    | 
| scat=>varchar     |
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    include "db_connect.php";  // including configuration file
?>
<form name="frmdropdown" method="post" action="sample.php">
<center>
        <h2 align="center">Select State</h2>
        <strong> Select State : </strong>
<select name="getData">
        <option value="">ALL--(<?php echo "" . $totalusa;?>) </option>
<?php
        $dd_res=mysqli_query($con,"Select DISTINCT sstate, count(sstate) AS state from sup GROUP BY sup.sstate");   
            while($r=mysqli_fetch_row($dd_res))
                { echo "<option value='$r[0]'> $r[0]</option>";

                }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="Select" value="Select"/> 
<br><hr>
```

Result I get

```
Select State
-------------
| ALL       | 

| CA        | 

| CO        |

| FL        | 

| GA        |
```

What I want

```
Select State
+-------------------+

| ALL       |  

| CA (472)  | 

| CO  (7)   | 

| FL  (5)   | 

| GA   (45) |
```

Like this.each state in dropdown I want total counts of records in each state

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP array: count or sizeof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974385/php-array-count-or-sizeof)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not fetching second column from the mysqli results. Try as below.

```
<?php
        $dd_res=mysqli_query($con,"Select sstate, count(sstate) AS state from sup GROUP BY sstate");   
            while($r=mysqli_fetch_row($dd_res))
                { echo "<option value='$r[0]'> $r[0] ( $r[1] )</option>";

                }
?>
```

Comment: i'm glad that i could help you @gautambose

Answer (score 0):

Because countries can have multiple states and each state can have multiple cities when you join these 1 to many and 1 to many many your state count is inflated. So you need the distinct count of state. The city count is already unique to country and state, thus doesn't need the distinct. where as state is not unique to country city, thus distinct is needed. This of course assumes you want the count of unique states in each country.

```
SELECT c.name, count(distinct s.name) as statecount,  count(ci.name) citycount 
FROM countries c,states s,cities ci
WHERE ci.state_id = s.id 
  and s.country_id = c.id 
GROUP BY s.name
```

Consider the following example: 
http://rextester.com/ZGYF56786

[How to get count of State and city of country using SQL query from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510313/how-to-get-count-of-state-and-city-of-country-using-sql-query-from-database)